# Is there a video service that allows HTML5 projects to be played in unison?

Tags: video, video-player

Large organization that has thousands of videos and also thousands of elearning/html5 projects.    The HTML5 projects are very graphical and enhanced but look and play much like our video, albeit with interactions.    Is there software that would allow us to play this to our users all from one source that is not an LMS?

To add to this we have done this in the past using JWplayer and hosting almost statically using Akamai... but looking for a company that does this integrated so we don't have to loads multiple video types, control quality settings, and keep track of player issues.

The technology issue (I believe) is not really playing the HTML5 projects in XYZ's video player, it is HTML5 compliant so it will generally play fine.   The problem is the companies that do video hosting do not have general hosting abilities now (10+ years ago they did).   So we can't build out a folder for the projects or better, have it automated.   An HTML5 project is simply a folder on a web server that has a call to an index page that plays in a video player.

Comment: What do you call an "html5 project"? Is it just an HTML5 web page?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - An HTML5 project is just a collection of videos, pictures, HTML that plays as a slideshow/video.   Articulate and Captivate are industry standard programs that do these however we have done these in-house without using the programs.